# Работа с MySQL на C++

Tags: c++

Подскажите, что использовать для работы с MySQL в С++?
Все попытки поиска ведут на http://tangentsoft.net/mysql++/ . Помнится я работал с версией 3.0.9 и были какие-то проблемы со стабильной работой. Кто пользуется, как у них обстоят дела сейчас? Это единственная библиотека для работы с MySQL сервером из своего приложения?

Она поддерживает выполнение параллельных запросов?

Comment: А чем это не подходит: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/cpp/ ? Гугл меня привёл туда.

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить 2 ORM библиотеки, которые поддерживают  MySQL.

- [sqlpp11](https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11)
- [ODB](http://www.codesynthesis.com/products/odb/)

Лично я их не использовал(только смотрел видео с CppCon), но выглядят перспективно и куда лучше обычных текстовых SQL запросов. Кроме того, есть Qt, который имеет драйвер для MySQL, но это вынуждает использовать весь Qt, и если Вы его уже не используете, то и смысла ради одного SQL его использовать нет.

Comment: Я долгое время пользовался ODB, начиная с первой версии. Вначале велась активная разработка библиотеки, но со временем все приуныло. Автор не спешит переходить на современный c++. Текущая версия 2.4 не понятно как собрана и выложена в репозитории. Итог - старый код, который собирался не один год на более ранних версиях сейчас невозможно собрать ни на ODB из репозитория ни на собранной вручную. Разочаровался полностью. Очень не рекомендую. На днях перешел на sqlpp11.